# Site settings JavaScipt

Tags: javascript, master-page, site-settings

I have included some javascript to a master page of a site collection. The script makes a clickable button directs to two sites which when an internal user click on it user directs to a internal accessible site while an external user click it directs to a external accessible site.

This button appears in all the sites except when I go to the site settings page of a particular site page.

Does that means the script is not working in site settings page? It works in site settings when I activate SharePoint Server Publishing feature in site features.

I'll add the code below you to clarify the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clientContext;
var user;

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady() {


    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    clientContext.load(user);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {

var cuser = user.get_email();
userem = cuser.replace(/.*@/, "");


if (userem == "xxx.com") {

document.getElementById("homehelp").innerHTML = "<a id='bookmarkmy' href='site url for internal users' title='Click here for help with this portal' target='_blank'><img src='image url' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;HELP</a>";

} else { 
  document.getElementById("homehelp").innerHTML = "<a id='bookmarkmy' href='site url for external users' title='Click here for help with this portal' target='_blank'><img src='image url' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;HELP</a>";
}


}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
</script>
```

Comment: So why you do not want to activate SP server publishing feature? Found a similar question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158673/custom-javascipt-within-site-settings

Comment: Because of resource usage and unwanted library creations we cant activate the feature in all the sites ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are needed to activate this feature to achieve your goal. It is clearly mentioned in that feature. Have a look on the description of this feature.

**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure:**

> Provides centralized libraries, content types, master pages and page
>   layouts and enables page scheduling and other publishing functionality
>   for a site collection.

[image]
 Moreover check this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/158675/21421)

```
if (userem == "xxx.com") {

document.getElementById("homehelp").innerHTML = "<a id='bookmarkmy' href='site url for internal users' title='Click here for help with this portal' target='_blank'><img src='image url' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;HELP</a>";

} else { 
  document.getElementById("homehelp").innerHTML = "<a id='bookmarkmy' href='site url for external users' title='Click here for help with this portal' target='_blank'><img src='image url' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-5px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;HELP</a>";
}
```

`homehelp` may not exist in Site Settings page. Check it.

Comment: But the issue is i have added a favorite button with java script which bookmark the particular page, that button shows in all the pages without any issue even in the site settings page how is this happening ?? :O

Comment: Are you using same master page for System Master Page also? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/158675/21421

Comment: Yes same master page

Comment: Can you check this script in the site settings page? Open the source of site settings page from browser and try to find your script block

Comment: Yes the script is there but how it doesn't show in the page when loading ??

Comment: Find homehelp element also. Check if it exists.

Comment: <div id="homehelp" style="z-index:100; position:fixed;top:60px;right:340px;">

</div> The div tag is there on the page source

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f

Comment: so your idea is that i have disabled scripting capabilities right ? but how is it possible to work some scripts while some others are not working ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Site Settings page doesn't load sp.js.

Try adding this before your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

See this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125580/sp-js-file-not-loaded-in-a-simple-jsom-example) for more.